# Error when including winuser.h. It defines ChangeMenu to ChangeMenuW or ChangeMenuA

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2017

Working on a Qt app on Windows. I include QVboxLayout in my source file only and this causes errors because its macro overwrites my method name.

```
foo.hpp
class foo
{
    ChangeMenu();
}

foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
#include "QVBoxLayout" // <--- this includes winuser.h

foo::ChangeMenu(){};
```

Now what happens is winuser.h has a macro

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define ChangeMenu  ChangeMenuW
#else
#define ChangeMenu  ChangeMenuA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

This changes my function definition to ChangeMenuW but my declaration is still ChangeMenu.

How should I solve this? How can winuser.h define such a "normal" name as a macro?

Version of winuser.h is "windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0"

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much any Windows API that deals with strings is actually a macro that resolves to a A or W version. There's no way around, you can either:

- avoid including `windows.h`, but as you noticed, it creeps through;
- brutally `#undef` the macro before defining/using your function; this is a fit punishment for hoarding such normal and non-macro-looking identifiers, but is tedious and some other code may actually need the Win32 function;
- just accept it as a sad fact of life and avoid all the relevant Win32 APIs names; if you use Qt and follow its naming convention, it should be easy, as Qt functions use lowerCamelCase (as opposed to Win32 UpperCamelCase);
- include `windows.h` explicitly straight in your header (possibly under an `#ifdef _WIN32`); this will make sure that your identifier *will* get replaced by the macro in all instances, so everything will work fine even if the compiler will actually compile a function with a different name; suitable for standalone projects, *not* suitable for libraries. (Thanks *@Jonathan Potter* for suggesting this)

Comment: Another solution would be to `#include <windows.h>` yourself, so that everything sees a consistent view of the macros it defines.

Comment: Any idea where to report this?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: oh yeah, that's actually how I got away with this several times. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: It's common practice to wrap the `#undef` inside [push_macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/push-macro) and [pop_macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pop-macro) pragmas. That way your code's changes don't spill out into the exterior environment. @vuk: Report it as a defect to the Qt Company. They pulled in unnecessary header files, and loads of macros along the way. Don't hold your breath, though. This is something they will not fix (like all the other harder to solve/tedious to fix bugs).

Comment: @IInspectable: the problem is that push/pop will work for your code, but then your client easily won't be able to use your function (well, it will have to perform this trick as well).

Comment: There's a tradeoff you have to make: Either break client code that calls your code, or break client code that calls the Windows API. The latter is harder to fix.

Answer (score 0):

You could take no care about this issue, Although your method name will be the same as the windows API, but the system will not mix them(just unify Unicode on both the place to define/call). If you call the `ChangeMenu()` directly, you will call the winapi, and if

```
foo f;
f.ChangeMenu();
```

or

`foo::ChangeMenu();`(static)

You will call your method.

And if you want to disable the winapi:

```
#ifdef ChangeMenu
#undef ChangeMenu
    //code place that you define/call your own ChangeMenu().
#ifdef UNICODE
#define ChangeMenu  ChangeMenuW
#else
#define ChangeMenu  ChangeMenuA
#endif // !UNICODE
#endif
```

(It looks very tedious.)

Comment: Why would you report this as an issue to Microsoft?. Clearly it would be impossible for them to change, and their header file is behaving precisely as defined. If there is an issue it is that a Qt header file includes a Windows header file, so if any issue might be reported it would have to be to the Qt developers.

Comment: Good luck trying to persuade Microsoft to remove this one function from their header files. If you think that the problem here is the Microsoft header files then I am afraid you are deluding yourself. This is a Qt issue.